# Ошибка сервера 500 после POST запроса через WebClient на C#

Tags: c#, post, запрос, webclient

Вот так выглядит запрос. В ответ на него сервер возвращает ошибку 500 в **Visual Studio 2017** на Windows. Причём в **Visual Studio Code** на Ubuntu запрос обрабатывается правильно и сервер не возвращает ошибок. Ладно бы, но программу нужно предоставить в виде решения Visual Studio.

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "token ...");
    webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    var response = webClient.UploadString(url, "POST", data);

    Console.WriteLine(response);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл решение. Если у кого такая же проблема, вставьте эту строку вначале:

`webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;`

В UploadString И UploadStringAsync методах это свойство используется для преобразования заданной строки в Byte массива перед отправкой строки.

В итоге код должен выглядеть так:

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "token ...");
    webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    var response = webClient.UploadString(url, "POST", data);

    Console.WriteLine(response);
}
```